# How to find starting index of a string if it contains any element from a list of substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Suppose, I have a list of substring below:

```
my_list = ["am", "is", "are"]
```

I want to search elements of this list in a string. If the string includes any item from the list, then starting index of this substring in the string should be printed.

The string is:

```
s = "I am a Python developer."
```

It is obvious that the string contains `"am"` and starting index of this substring in string is `2`.

Once I thought to use:

```
if "am" in s:
    print(s.find("am"))
```

but I limited searching operation by only one element of list. There can be at most an item from list in the string.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Could you give an example of expected output?

Comment: Have you learned about loops yet?

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop:

```
for item in my_list:
    print(s.find(item))
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to search the string for the elements in your list, and return the index of the first match. We exit on the first match found (since you want *any* element, there's no need to test remaining substrings past that point).

```
def find_index_first_match(target, *args):
    for arg in args:
        search = target.find(arg)
        # If arg is not in target, search is -1.
        if search >= 0:
            return search    
    # You could return -1 here so the return's more
    # consistent with str.find's behavior.
    return None


find_index_first_match(s, *my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even split the string and search:

my_list = ["am", "is", "are"]

s = "I am a Python developer."
split_s = s.split()

for item in my_list:
if item in split_s:
print("Found this word in string s: "+item)

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over your list:

```
for item in my_list:
    if item in s:
        print(s.find(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ["am", "is", "are"]
#s = "I am a Python developer."
s = "I am a Python developer and is are blah."
test=dict(enumerate(s.split(' '),1))
[k for k,v in test.items() if v in my_list]
```

Output:

```
[2, 7, 8]
```

you can use `enumerate` and create a `dictionary` out of the string and use list comprehension with an if clause to get the index if it exists in your other list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
i = min(len(s.split(w,1)[0]) for w in my_list) # 2
```

This is how it works:

- `for p in my_list` is a comprehension that goes through the keywords one by one
- `s.split(p,1)[0]` uses the keyword (w) to split the string and picks up the left part of the split (prefix).  It will contain all the characters preceding the keyword (or the whole string if the keyword is not present)
- `len(...)` gets the size of the prefixes obtained from the comprehension. This will correspond to the position (index) of the keyword.
- `min(...` selects the smallest size of keyword prefixes which corresponds to the index of the first keyword found in `s`

Another option would be to use a regular expression formed by combining your list of keywords:

```
import re
pattern = r'\b('+"|".join(my_list)+r')\b' # \b(am|is|are)\b

i = re.search(pattern,s).start() # 2
```